# Creating win forms programmatically?

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm having a bit of an issue in doing this. I need to create windows forms programmatically from my startup class.

I have a foreach loop like this:

```
int count = 1;
foreach (User user in User.AllUsers)
{
    Form myForm = new Form();
    myForm.Text = "User: " + count;
    myForm.Show();

    count ++;
}
```

The problem is that I need the "myForm" name to be variable so each created form will have a different name that I can later refer to, like; myForm1, myForm2, myForm3 and so on. I tried a variety of things but you can't assign a variable to that name.

How do you do this?

Comment: ASP.NET is a web platform - can you please clarify why you would want to create winforms on the webforms platform? Your question is very confused and can't be answered in its current state.

Comment: the fact it is tagged winforms suggests it was a typo

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hold references to multiple objects, you store them as elements in a collection, not in multiple separate variables.

```
int count = 1;
List<Form> formInstances = new List<Form>();
foreach (User user in User.AllUsers)
{
    Form myForm = new Form();
    myForm.Text = "User: " + count;
    myForm.Show();
    formInstances.Add(myForm);
    count ++;
}
```

However, as Oded has already commented, you can't use WinForms in ASP.NET, so you need to think again about exactly what you're trying to achieve, then get a good book and learn about .NET programming.

Comment: I'm developing a winforms .NET application and wrongly tagged it ASP.NET, it is corrected now.

Steve your answer seems to have solved the problem, I didn't think it could be done that way. Thanks.